# all possible combinations

Tags: algorithm

I have a math problem that goes as follows:

I have a container which holds a total of 21000 kilos.
I have 4 items A,B,C,D .

Item A weights 1 kilo.
Item B weights 4 kilos.
Item C weight 5 kilos.
Item D weights 5 kilos also.

I am looking for an algorithm that will iterate through all possible combinations keeping the above equation. for example:

{20000 , 0, 0, 200} --> **20000*1 + 0*4 + 0*5 + 200*5** = 21000 kilos.

{19996, 1, 0, 200}  --> **19996*1 + 1*4 + 0*5 + 200*5** = 21000 kilos.

Comment: @dthorpe Sounds like it to me.

Comment: Are you sure you want to iterate over all possible combinations? What exactly are you trying to do? Solve the knapsack problem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: What are you going to do with the tens or hundreds of thousands of solutions?

Comment: If it's homework then it's very weird. Homework problems usually give you `N` kilos, not ... 21000.

Comment: haha..guys school was done years ago. i wish!

To answer your questions: I am solving this just for the fun of it. yes this is fun for me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to the "Counting Change" example from SICP.  See:

http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.2

Example: Counting Change

Comment: It certainly is.  Here's another post on it too:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106929/find-all-combinations-of-coins-when-given-some-dollar-value

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve `a + 4b + 5c + 5d = 20000 (a,b,c,d >=0)`

or `a + 4b = 2000 - 5e =  5(400-e)` where `e = c + d`

so `a + 4b` can be `0, 5, 10, 15, 20, ..., 2000`

you can easily find all possible values of `a` and `b` from above

after that you know the value of `e = c + d`, from there you can easily find all possible values of `c` and `d`.