# Ruby - "Vending Machine" returning Change

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum

In ruby, I'm trying to make a simple financial script to **return a group of numbers `[i]`** that represents the **amount `[n]` inputed** by the user.

My array holds "pieces" of an payment: `[5.0, 1.5, 0.5, 2, 1]` into installments of the total amount.

> *Example:* In a `arr = [5.0, 1.5, 0.5, 2, 1]` the **total amount** is equal to `10.0`.

If the user inputs `4.5`, the  method should return `[i]`  as `[1.5, 2, 1]`.

Anyone could help me building the `[i]` method?

Comment: Are you looking for a subset of `arr` that sums to the desired value?  If so, do the values have to be contiguous?  How do you know that the sum is always achievable?  I think you need to edit your question, it's currently quite ambiguous.

Comment: Why would input of `4.5` return `[1.5, 2, 1]`? That doesn't explain any pattern. What happens with `9.4`? `-0.1`? `9834455.0`?

Comment: If the result is well-defined, then what's the logic? You didn't explain this at all in your question. (Even if you need to choose values from the original `arr`, it's srtill ambiguous -- Should `2` be represented as `[1.5, 0.5]`, or `[1, 1]`, or `[2]`?) If the result is random, then what are the constraints? (Are we limited to that `arr`? Can we repeat values? What if there's no solution?) Again, you didn't specify this at all in your question.

Comment: I am voting to close this question, as it's unclear what you are asking. You need to give precise requirements; this is ambiguous and open to interpretation.

Comment: Short way: `arr.reduce(0.0, &:+)`.

Comment: I've a amount of values that represents a full payment, in this case, the full amount is equal to `10`. My array holds "pieces" of this payment, into **installments** of the total amount. So if someone pays me `3.5`, I know in my array should return `2` and `1.5` values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pjs said, your question looks quite ambigious.

If you want to get a sum of array just use: `array.reduce(0.0, &:+)` or even `array.sum`.

If you want to get an array that will sum into given `N` then you didnt give us sufficient details. What are limits? Can't you just do something like `4.5 -> [1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5]` ?

#### upd

Author gave us a details. We have the array `[5.0, 1.5, 0.5, 2, 1]` and by given number `N` we should find a sum consisted of numbers from this array that equals `N`. Basically it is like vending machine change problem (what coins should it give to customer).

You can google it just like that "vending machine change algorithm". For example: [Java Algorithm to solve vendor machine 'change giving' problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067044/java-algorithm-to-solve-vendor-machine-change-giving-problem)

Here's my simple dynamic programming solution:

```
ALLOWED_NUMBERS = [5.0, 1.5, 0.5, 2, 1].sort.freeze

def into_sum_of_allowed_numbers(n)
  return [] if n == 0
  @cache ||= {}
  return @cache[n] if @cache[n]

  ALLOWED_NUMBERS.reverse_each do |x|
    next if n - x < 0
    lesser_sum = into_sum_of_allowed_numbers(n - x)
    next unless lesser_sum
    @cache[n] = lesser_sum + [x]
    return @cache[n]
  end
  nil
end

into_sum_of_allowed_numbers(4.5) # ==> [0.5, 2, 2]
```

Basically, the idea is simple. With allowed numbers `a, b, c` sum for number `n` is `[*sum_for(n - a), a]` or `[*sum_for(n - c), c]` or `[*sum_for(n - c), c]`.

You can do this without `@cache` though it will be much slower.

I guess there're better solutions but recursive one looks most simple to me.

Comment: I've a amount of values that represents a full payment, in this case, the full amount is equal to 10. My array holds "pieces" of this payment `[5.0, 1.5, 0.5, 2, 1]` into installments of the total amount. So, if someone pays me 3.5, I know in my array should return `2` and `1.5` values

Comment: @gbs0 ah, so, basically, you have a problem close to vending machine change problem

Comment: @gbs0 see my updated answer. And edit your initial question

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!! Gives me a light for keep going!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ruby 2.4 or higher, you can just do `arr.sum`, to find the sum of an array containing only numbers.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum