# given n, how to find the number of different ways to write n as the sum of 1, 3, 4 in ruby？

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Problem: given n, find the number of different ways to write n as the sum of 1, 3, 4
Example:for n=5, the answer is 6

```
 5=1+1+1+1+1
 5=1+1+3
 5=1+3+1
 5=3+1+1
 5=1+4
 5=4+1
```

I have tried with permutation method,but its efficiency is very low,is there  a more efficient way to do？

Comment: This smells like homework. Am I right or is there some sort of practical problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @mu is too short,no,this is a topic I see on a page, I tried, I use a brute force method, inefficient, so for help

Comment: @ Cary Swoveland–- (The first would be to determine the different numbers of 1s, 3s and 4s that sum to the given number. For n = 5, there are only 3, which we could write [[5,0,0], [2,1,0], [1,0,1]])--how to generate it by program?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm giving some thought as to how that could be done efficiently. I might have something for you tomorrow. Perhaps others will makes suggestions also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine the combinations of making change for a given amount](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518261/determine-the-combinations-of-making-change-for-a-given-amount)

Comment: @Anonymous, it may be a duplicate, but I think both answers given here are quite a bit better than the answers given to the previous question.

Comment: I deleted three lengthy comments I left before deciding to post an answer, as I've incorporated those points in my answer. I mention this as the OP left a comment above that addressed those comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using dynamic programming with a lookup table (implemented with a hash, as it makes the code simpler):

```
nums=[1,3,4]
n=5

table={0=>1}
1.upto(n) { |i|
  table[i] = nums.map { |num| table[i-num].to_i }.reduce(:+)
}
table[n]
# => 6
```

Note: Just checking one of the other answers, mine was instantaneous for n=500.

Comment: Very impressive! When I first saw this I thought it couldn't be right, being so short, but it is. I confess I'm still puzzled by one aspect, but let me think about that a bit more.  I presume `.to_i` is to deal with `nil`s (clever).  @sawa, be sure to see this.

Comment: I see how you came up with such an elegant solution: you're one of those "Earth" guys.

Comment: It was longer, but I refactor it a bit.. yes, `.to_i` is for `nil`s, and hash is so that I don't have to bother with negative indexes. What on earth is an "Earth" guy? :)

Comment: Key to Karoly's answer as well as mine is recurrence relation. This one uses it better. By the way, if you start with `table = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = 0}`, then you can get rid of `to_i`. I also wonder whether you can use `inject` or `each_with_object` for the outer iteration.

Comment: @sawa: it's possible, but first you have to build the whole table so you can iterate over it. I don't know any functional loop construct that allows you to refer to previously (int the loop) *created* list/hash elements. But the again, I'm not that experienced in ruby...

Answer (score 2):

```
def add_next sum, a1, a2
  residue = a1.inject(sum, :-)
  residue.zero? ? [a1] : a2.reject{|x| residue < x}.map{|x| a1 + [x]}
end

a = [[]]
until a == (b = a.flat_map{|a| add_next(5, a, [1, 3, 4])})
  a = b
end
```

`a`:

```
[
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 3],
  [1, 3, 1],
  [1, 4],
  [3, 1, 1],
  [4, 1]
]

a.length #=> 6
```

Comment: I look forward to having a close look at this in the morning.

Comment: this is a nice ruby mind twister, wouldn't like to code review it though :) check my answer, it's a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this problem should be addressed in two steps.

*Step 1*

The first step is to determine the different numbers of `1`s, `3`s and `4`s that sum to the given number. For `n = 5`, there are only 3, which we could write:

```
[[5,0,0], [2,1,0], [1,0,1]]
```

These 3 elements are respectively interpreted as "five 1s, zero 3s and zero 4s", "two 1s, one 3 and zero 4s" and "one 1, zero 3s and one 4".

To compute these combinations efficiently, I first I compute the possible combinations using only 1s, that sum to each number between zero and 5 (which of course is trivial). These values are saved in a hash, whose keys are the summands and the value is the numbers of 1's needed to sum to the value of the key:

```
h0 = { 0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5 }
```

(If the first number had been 2, rather than 1, this would have been:

```
h0 = { 0 => 0, 2 => 1, 4 => 2 }
```

since there is no way to sum only 2s to equal 1 or 3.)

Next we consider using both 1 and 3 to sum to each value between 0 and 5. There are only two choices for the number of 3s used, zero or one.  This gives rise to the hash:

```
h1 = { 0 => [[0,0]], 1 => [[1,0]], 2 => [[2,0]], 3 => [[3,0], [0,1]],
  4 => [[4,0], [1,1]], 5 => [[5,0], [2,1]] }
```

This indicates, for example, that:

- there is only 1 way to use 1 and 3 to sum to 1: `1 => [1,0]`, meaning one 1 and zero 3s.
- there are two ways to sum to 4: `4 => [[4,0], [1,1]]`, meaning four 1s and zero 3s or one 1 and one 3.

Similarly, when 1, 3 and 4 can all be used, we obtain the hash:

```
h2 = { 5 => [[5,0,0], [2,1,0], [1,0,1]] }
```

Since this hash corresponds to the use of all three numbers, 1, 3 and 4, we are concerned only with the combinations that sum to 5.

In constructing `h2`, we can use zero 4s or one 4. If we use use zero 4s, we would use one 1s and 3s that sum to 5. We see from `h1` that there are two combinations:

```
5 => [[5,0], [2,1]]
```

For `h2` we write these as:

```
[[5,0,0], [2,1,0]]
```

If one 4 is used, 1s and 3s totalling 5 - 1*4 = 1 are used.  From `h1` we see there is just one combination:

```
1 => [[1,0]]
```

which for `h2` we write as

```
[[1,0,1]]
```

so

the value for the key `5` in `h2` is:

```
[[5,0,0], [2,1,0]] + [[1,0,1]] = [[5,0,0], [2,1,0]], [1,0,1]]
```

Aside: because of form of hashes I've chosen to represent hashes `h1` and `h2`, it is actually more convenient to represent `h0` as:

```
h0 = { 0 => [[0]], 1 => [[1]],..., 5 => [[5]] }
```

It should be evident how this sequential approach could be used for any collection of integers whose combinations are to be summed.

*Step 2*

The numbers of distinct arrangements of each array `[n1, n3, n4]` produced in Step 1 equals:

```
(n1+n3+n4)!/(n1!n3!n4!)
```

Note that if one of the `n`'s were zero, these would be binomial coefficients. If fact, these are coefficients from the [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), which is a generalization of the binomial distribution. The reasoning is simple. The numerator gives the number of permutations of all the numbers. The `n1` 1s can be permuted `n1!` ways for each distinct arrangement, so we divide by `n1!`. Same for `n3` and `n4`

For the example of summing to `5`, there are:

- `5!/5! = 1` distinct arrangement for `[5,0,0]`
- `(2+1)!/(2!1!) = 3` distinct arrangements for `[2,1,0]` and
- `(1+1)!/(1!1!) = 2` distinct arrangements for `[1,0,1]`, for a total of:

`1+3+2 = 6` distinct arrangements for the number 5.

**Code**

```
def count_combos(arr, n)
  a = make_combos(arr,n)
  a.reduce(0) { |tot,b| tot + multinomial(b) }
end

def make_combos(arr, n)
  arr.size.times.each_with_object([]) do |i,a|
    val = arr[i]
    if i.zero?
      a[0] = (0..n).each_with_object({}) { |t,h|
        h[t] = [[t/val]] if (t%val).zero? }
    else
      first = (i==arr.size-1) ? n : 0 
      a[i] = (first..n).each_with_object({}) do |t,h|
        combos = (0..t/val).each_with_object([]) do |p,b|
          prev = a[i-1][t-p*val]
          prev.map { |pr| b << (pr +[p]) } if prev
        end
        h[t] = combos unless combos.empty?
      end    
    end
  end.last[n]
end

def multinomial(arr)
  (arr.reduce(:+)).factorial/(arr.reduce(1) { |tot,n|
    tot * n.factorial })
end
```

and a helper:

```
class Fixnum
  def factorial
    return 1 if self < 2
    (1..self).reduce(:*)
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
count_combos([1,3,4], 5)     #=> 6
count_combos([1,3,4], 6)     #=> 9
count_combos([1,3,4], 9)     #=> 40
count_combos([1,3,4], 15)    #=> 714
count_combos([1,3,4], 30)    #=> 974169
count_combos([1,3,4], 50)    #=> 14736260449
count_combos([2,3,4], 50)    #=> 72581632   
count_combos([2,3,4,6], 30)  #=> 82521
count_combos([1,3,4], 500)   #1632395546095013745514524935957247\
  00017620846265794375806005112440749890967784788181321124006922685358001
```

(I broke the result the example (one long number) into two pieces, for display purposes.)

`count_combos([1,3,4], 500)` took about 2 seconds to compute; the others were essentially instantaneous.

@sawa's method and mine gave the same results for `n` between 6 and 9, so I'm confident they are both correct. sawa's solution times increase much more quickly with `n` than do mine, because he is computing and then counting all the permutations.

Edit: @Karole, who just posted an answer, and I get the same results for all my tests (including the last one!). Which answer do I prefer?  Hmmm. Let me think about that.)

Comment: I just realized this post. I knew you were going to do something with this.

Comment: are you sure your results are correct? check my post.

Comment: Karoly, I re-ran that test and got the same 105-digit number that you got! (See edit.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ruby so I am writing it in C++
say for your example n=5.
Use dynamic programming set

```
int D[n],n;
cin>>n;
D[0]=1;
D[1]=1;
D[2]=1;
D[3]=2; 
for(i = 4; i <= n; i++)
    D[i] = D[i-1] + D[i-3] + D[i-4];
cout<<D[i];
```

Comment: on what basis did you initialise D[0]=1;