# Recursion logic to calculate coin change/football score

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to understand the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106929/find-all-combinations-of-coins-when-given-some-dollar-value/1106973#1106973) posted in stackflow.

I was trying to use the recursion logic given as one of the answers to calculate NFL score

```
score = 10
points = [7, 3, 2]
names = {7: "touchdown", 3: "field goals", 2 : "safeties"}

def count_combs(left, i, comb, add):
    if add: comb.append(add)
    if left == 0 or (i+1) == len(points):

        if (i+1) == len(points) and left > 0:
            comb.append( (left, points[i]) )
            i += 1
        while i < len(points):
            comb.append( (0, points[i]) )
            i += 1
        print " ".join("%d %s" % (n,names[c]) for (n,c) in comb)
        return 1
    cur = points[i]
    return sum(count_combs(left-x*cur, i+1, comb[:], (x,cur)) for x in range(0, int(left/cur)+1))

print count_combs(score, 0, [], None)
```

The value coming out is incorrect.

```
0 touchdown 0 field goals 10 safeties
```

It must be 5 safeties not 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code incorrectly assumes that the last value of `points` is always going to be `1`. That was probably a good assumption when dealing with money since there's almost always going to be a coin of denomination 1, but it's not right for your football version of the code.

The error is in this in the block:

```
     if (i+1) == len(points) and left > 0:
        comb.append( (left, points[i]) )
        i += 1
```

A more correct implementation of that block needs to do two things differently. First, it needs to make sure that `left` is divisible by `points[i]`, since otherwise you can't get the desired score with the kind of points left. It also needs to use `left/points[i]` in the `append` call, since it can't rely on the last value being `1`.

Here's a fixed version of the code, with comments on the new stuff:

```
def count_combs(left, i, comb, add):
    if add: comb.append(add)
    if left == 0 or (i+1) == len(points):
        if (i+1) == len(points) and left > 0:
            if left % points[i]: # can't get the exact score with this kind of points
                return 0         # so give up on this recursive branch
            comb.append( (left/points[i], points[i]) ) # fix the amount here
            i += 1
        while i < len(points):
            comb.append( (0, points[i]) )
            i += 1
        print " ".join("%d %s" % (n,names[c]) for (n,c) in comb)
        return 1
    cur = points[i]
    return sum(count_combs(left-x*cur, i+1, comb[:], (x,cur)) for x in range(0, int(left/cur)+1))
```

Comment: yes, this thing with 1 is commonly overlooked. I also deal with it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50087510/849891), though in [tag:Scheme]. (FYI.)