# Problem in thinking recursively. How to take recursive leap of faith?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

The common guidelines I follow to solve problems recursively is do divide the problems in subproblems and solve for the smaller inputs. If it works, it would work for bigger inputs as well (*Recursive leap of faith*).

So with I tried solving this problem. Find all subsets of an `arr`;

> For e.g if arr = [1, 2, 3]
>
> The output should be:
>
> [3, 2, 1] [2, 1] [3, 1] [1] [3, 2] [2] [3] []

So the way I thought was to divide this in smaller problems.
for e.g `f(n) = {arr[0], {f(arr[0], f(n-1)} }`

and came up with this solution:

```
var res = [];
function recur(arr){
if(arr.length === 1) {
  return arr[0];
}

for(let elem of arr){
    res.push(elem);
  
    res.push([elem, recur(arr.filter(k=> k!== elem))]);
}
return res;
}


console.log(recur([1,2]))
```

Now while this works for smaller inputs lime `[1]` or `[1, 5]` It's certainly a *wrong* solution and it wouldn't work for other inputs.

The correct solution would be something like this:

```js
function recur(arr, ind=0, res=[]){

 function subsequence(arr, ind=0, res=[]){
   if(ind === arr.length){
      console.log(res);
      return
    }
    subsequence(arr, ind+1, [arr[ind], ...res]);
    subsequence(arr, ind+1, res);
 }
 
 
subsequence(arr, ind, res)

}

recur([1,2,3],0, []);
```

Now here are my questions:

1. Am I wrong to follow the above guidelines as it is or have I misinterpreted?
2. Are there any finite list of patterns which I can practice to be able to solve any kind of recursive problems or the pattern is just endless

Comment: Why is your solution "wrong" and "not working" for other inputs (indeed, you did not say what the goal of the function is either)?

Comment: @topsail I just edited.

Comment: The advice is good, but means this is advice for generating provable *algorithms*. It does not mean that all recursive code is correct. Notably, code that mutates parameters should always be treated with suspicion.

Comment: The more "normal" solution would be something that doesn't mutate inputs or globals, more like
`function subsequence(arr) {
   if (arr.length == 1) return arr;
   var res = [arr];
   for(let elem of arr)
       res.concat(subsequence(arr.filter(k=> k!== elem)));
   return res;
}`

Comment: "Recursive leap of faith" is this: *assume it works* for smaller inputs, *use* it to construct  solution for bigger inputs which is *provably correct* under that assumption. prove base cases are correct. QED.

Comment: Recursive functions that simply log within their base case aren't generally useful. Prefer writing functions that return results so they can be used programmatically, and optionally logged by the caller only if desired.

Comment: This is the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Recursive_definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. I would formulate the "recursive leap of faith" differently: *Assuming* you have correct solutions to the subproblems, how can you "combine" them to a correct solution of the "whole" problem? This is how you come up with the "recursion". Then you just need to figure out the "base case" (solution to the trivial problem), verify that the step indeed reduces to the base case, and you're good.
2. No, there is no finite list of patterns. All problems *can* be solved "recursively" (purely functionally), so if there was a simple list of patterns, algorithm design would be a solved problem, but it isn't. You're never "done" learning. (Within the scope of a course however, you can usually expect your problems to be simple enough and somewhat similar to practice problems, such that the techniques you have learnt can be used to solve them.)

Now let's look at your problem as an example: Finding all subsets of an array (represented by a set).

*Let's pretend we already have the problem solved for smaller sets*. So our array has n elements, but we have only solved the problem *somehow* for sets of size n - 1. How could we possibly take advantage of this? We need to "reduce" our problem: Let's remove an element. Then, solve the reduced subproblem for the set with one less element. We can assume that this solution is correct, taking the "leap of faith".

Now, how do we construct all subsets of the original set from this? Easy: To be subsets of our original sets, all these subsets can also contain the element we removed, or they don't.

Now what's the base case? If a set is empty, there is only one subset: The empty set.

In code:

```js
function findSubsets(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return [[]] // base case
    }
    let smaller_arr = [...arr] // copy array
    let element = smaller_arr.pop() // reduce problem by removing an element
    // this recursive call is where we take the "leap of faith"
    let subsets_of_smaller_arr = findSubsets(smaller_arr)
    // now construct the solution to the "larger" problem from this
    let subsets = [...subsets_of_smaller_arr] // all subsets of the smaller set are also subsets of this set; be careful to copy again
    for (let subset_of_smaller_arr of subsets_of_smaller_arr) {
        // subsets of the smaller set can additionally have the removed element added to it
        subsets.push([...subset_of_smaller_arr, element])
    }
    return subsets
}
```

Or perhaps, for another example of a recursive algorithm, consider Merge Sort:

- The base cases are arrays of length 0 or 1, which are already sorted.
- Merge Sort splits the array into two halves, recursively calling itself to sort the two halves. The *recursive leap of faith* here is that we assume that these recursive calls work correctly.
- Merge Sort then *merges* these two sorted arrays into one sorted array. This can only be done efficiently *because* we can assume them to be sorted.

---

> The common guidelines I follow to solve problems recursively is [to]  divide the problems in subproblems and solve for the smaller inputs. If it works, it would work for bigger inputs as well (Recursive leap of faith).

You need to be careful here: Your "base cases" are where you "solve for smaller inputs" when designing a recursive algorithm. Your *recursion* / "dividing" the problem and then "combining" solutions *must work for problems of any size (that are not base cases)* (and assuming the solutions to the subproblems are correct).

If you're all out of ideas, you can try to come up with a *recursion* by looking at and solving small problems, *but then you need to verify that it generalizes (works for all problems of size larger than the base case)* (which in this case it doesn't).

---

As an exercise, I recommend you to devise *another* recursion for finding all subsets of an array: Instead of taking out a single element, you can also *split the array in the middle* and *recursively find the subsets of the two halves*, then "merge" the two by going through all combinations of these two subsets. Try to implement this, and convince yourself of its correctness.

Comment: Thanks. Your insights are helpful. I tried to think the same way for solving another problem. Couldn't elaborate in the comment so here I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77562343/find-permutation-of-array-where-am-i-going-wrong